Why do i always get this attribute error whever i use the pip command
Whenever i try and do anything using the pip command i get this error.
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 160, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 247, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 326, in run
    session = self.get_default_session(options)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 98, in get_default_session
    self._session = self.enter_context(self._build_session(options))
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 125, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 343, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 175, in user_agent
    setuptools_dist = get_default_environment().get_distribution("setuptools")
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 188, in get_distribution
    return next(matches, None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 183, in <genexpr>
    matches = (
              ^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/base.py", line 612, in iter_all_distributions
    for dist in self._iter_distributions():
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 176, in _iter_distributions
    for dist in finder.find_eggs(location):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 144, in find_eggs
    yield from self._find_eggs_in_dir(location)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 111, in _find_eggs_in_dir
    from pip._vendor.pkg_resources import find_distributions
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2164, in <module>
    register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 31, in <module>
    sys.exit(_main())
             ^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 70, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 101, in main
    return self._main(args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 216, in _main
    self.handle_pip_version_check(options)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 179, in handle_pip_version_check
    session = self._build_session(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 125, in _build_session
    session = PipSession(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 343, in __init__
    self.headers["User-Agent"] = user_agent()
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/network/session.py", line 175, in user_agent
    setuptools_dist = get_default_environment().get_distribution("setuptools")
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 188, in get_distribution
    return next(matches, None)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 183, in <genexpr>
    matches = (
              ^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/base.py", line 612, in iter_all_distributions
    for dist in self._iter_distributions():
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 176, in _iter_distributions
    for dist in finder.find_eggs(location):
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 144, in find_eggs
    yield from self._find_eggs_in_dir(location)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_internal/metadata/importlib/_envs.py", line 111, in _find_eggs_in_dir
    from pip._vendor.pkg_resources import find_distributions
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2164, in <module>
    register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?

i tried all the command people suggested but i always get this error. when i ran python -m ensurepip --upgrade i got an externally managed enviorment error and the other commands always give me this one. The only thing i havent tried is setting up a virtual enviorment because i dont know the details of that.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read tag descriptions before using tags. From [tag:python-3.x]: "DO NOT USE UNLESS YOUR QUESTION IS FOR PYTHON 3 ONLY. Always use alongside the standard [python] tag."
